# How to read a JSON response in Unity?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am new to Unity and I have been trying read the JSON response from my RESTful API using C#. Here's what I've tried with LitJson:

```
JsonData jsonvale = JsonMapper.ToObject(www.text);

string parsejson;
parsejson = jsonvale["myapiresult"].ToString();
```

My JSON response is `{"myapiresult":"successfull"}`

For whatever reason, it doesn't work currently. I don't know how to fix it.

I also found a paid plugin for JSON.NET but I'm not sure if it will solve my problem.

Comment: Could you add the actual JSON response from your API to your question? How exactly doesn't your current code work?

Comment: I have added the JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to buy any paid plugins to use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) here. You can either create a class that models the response or deserialize to a dynamic object.

Example of the former:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// ...
class Response
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "myapiresult")]
    public string ApiResult { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    string responseJson = "{\"myapiresult\":\"successfull\"}";
    Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responseJson);
    Console.WriteLine(response.ApiResult);
    // Output: successfull
}
```

...and the latter:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// ...
void Main()
{
    string responseJson = "{\"myapiresult\":\"successfull\"}";
    dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseJson);
    Console.WriteLine(response.myapiresult.ToString());
    // Output: successfull
}
```